# When did the Toronto Club become gender neutral?

Tags: political-history, social-history

The [Toronto Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Club) is one of the most exclusive and oldest member's only clubs in Canada. It's entirely gender neutral today, but, presumably, that wasn't always the case.

So I'm wondering, when did that change? Or, if the club was always gender neutral, is there evidence of that somewhere (it's charter or otherwise proof)?

Comment: Since the term "gender neutral" is a fairly modern one, I'd suggest that the label only began to be applied in the last decade or two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gentlemen%27s_clubs_in_Canada#List_of_clubs says the switch was in 1993, citing  Kastner, Susan. "Men's clubby inner sanctum creaks open to admit women." Toronto Star, 27 June 1993, p. A1.

Comment: @kimchilover - My guess was going to be "during Prohibition in the USA", because that's when women in speakeasies (the only bar/nightclub equivalent still in existence in during prohibition) became A Thing.  Seems that's about right, although '33 was the year it ended.

Comment: @T.E.D. But in Canada did not enjoy/endure Prohibition, at least not in the USA sense of the term.  My impression of the Toronto Club was that it was not a speakeasy.

Comment: @kimchilover - Correct. But what prohibition did culturally in the USA was transform social public drinking from a male-only activity into a gender-neutral one. I'd imagine that would have made male-only clubs look like a bit of a dinosaur by the end. While the prohibition *laws* ended at the US border, the cultural changes likely did not.

Comment: Probably turn the comment into an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: The link in the question tells you the answer.

Comment: Voted to close as too basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia article [Toronto Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Club) "Membership at the Toronto Club is by invitation only and (as of 1993[3]) is completely gender-neutral." The cited reference is to an article in the Toronto *Star* by Susan Kastner:
"Men's clubby inner sanctum creaks open to admit women." Toronto Star, 27 June 1993, p. A1.  (I have not seen this article myself.)